# bundle exec not working with crontab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, bundle, cron

I'm trying to execute the following shell script using crontab:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /mnt/voylla-production/current
bundle exec rake maintenance:last_2_days_orders
bundle exec rake maintenance:send_last_2_days_payment_dropouts
```

The crontab entry is

```
0 16 * * * /mnt/voylla-production/releases/20131031003111/voylla_scripts/cj_4pm.sh
```

I'm getting the following error message in the mail:

```
/mnt/voylla-staging/current/voylla_scripts/cj_4pm.sh: line 3: bundle: command not found
/mnt/voylla-staging/current/voylla_scripts/cj_4pm.sh: line 4: bundle: command not found
```

I dont get the error when I run the commands manually. Not sure what's going on here. Could someone please point out.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using RVM or something like that? Cron tasks are executed in an environment different from your shell. Paths to ruby and gems are not set properly.

Comment: So google for "RVM crontab" :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : Thanks for the help, I should be able to take it from here.:)

Comment: I think you should use the full path for the bundle. Lets try to run " which bundle" in the app folder, you will get the full path for bundle command and then use it in the crontab.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A nice trick to get all environment properly set up in crontab is to use `/bin/bash -l` :

```
0 16 * * * /bin/bash -l -c '/mnt/voylla-production/releases/20131031003111/voylla_scripts/cj_4pm.sh'
```

The `-l` option will invoke a full login shell, thus reading your bashrc file and any path / rvm setting it performs.

If you want to simplify your crontab management and use this trick - as well as others - without having to think about them, you can use the [Whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever). It also play very nice with capistrano, if you use it, regenerating crontab on deploy.

Comment: This is the most accurate answer

Answer (score 8):

The user used by cron does not have the correct environment.
You can tell cron which user to use. For a bash script, you can so something like:

```
#!/bin/bash --login
source /home/user/.bashrc
rvm use 2.0.0@gemset #if you use rvm
cd /path/to/project && bundle exec xyz
```

Comment: This is also a great answer!, you can even add more lines to it.

Answer (score 0):

We need set right path to our bundle:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /mnt/voylla-production/current
/home/youruser/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec rake maintenance:last_2_days_orders
```