# Command to run a RUBY cron job on JUSTHOST

Tags: ruby, cron

My Cron Setup is:

```
0 * * * * ruby /directory/to/ruby/file.rb
```

And I get this error:

```
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mechanize (LoadError)
from /usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home4/ofixcom1/rails_apps/products.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

When I run that script on SSH it runs without a problem, but when I cron setup it gives me this error. I have read a lot of solutions. Even with RVM and I tried them almost all. 
A previous cron with ruby was running smoothly I dont know why it is not working with mine.

I forgot to mention, on the JustHost help they have this link with examples for other codes:
[Cron Setup](https://my.justhost.com/cgi/help/168)

Comment: Is cron running as the same user that you use when running it via SSH?

Comment: yes it is, JUSTHOST uses the same users for SSH than the CPANEL and so on.

Comment: Since cron doesn't run things in an interactive/login session, I suspect it's not loading e.g. `.bashrc` or `.profile` where the RVM environment is configured. You could try running `bash -l -c "ruby ..."` instead (as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19832002)). Failing that, googling various combinations of "cron," "RVM" and "bundler" turns up tons of results.

Comment: Hi Jordan, thank you for your reply, the .profile files are in directory /home4/ofixcom1 should I use this instead of bin/bash?

Comment: Hello Jordan after running  this code, it does not recognize the require, it looks like it think that this is a SH instead of ruby>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the cron command line type:

```
bash -l -c '/home4/USER/public_html/code.rb'
```

On top of your code.rb file add:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby
```

and also open and edit.bashcr just to make sure you have the gems directory included.

```
export HPATH=$HOME
export GEM_HOME=$HPATH/ruby/gems
export GEM_PATH=$GEM_HOME:/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.3
export GEM_CACHE=$GEM_HOME/cache
export PATH=$PATH:$HPATH/ruby/gems/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HPATH/ruby/gems
```

special thank you to Jordan, who gave me the answer to this issue.

note: when doing a full justhost wipeout. and inserting whereis ruby command I had to change

```
 #!/usr/local/bin/ruby
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

`rvm` has a [page](https://rvm.io/deployment/cron) dedicated to using RVM wrappers with `cron`. Basically, you can

- call directly the wrappers in `$rvm_path/wrappers/<ruby-version>[@gemset-name]`;
- use `rvm`'s alias wrappers
- load `rvm` environment in a shell script that is being invoked by `cron`