# A command of the gem whenever in cron doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, cron

I have a simple rails app **with the gem whenever**. And there's a module:

```
module Module1
  class << self
    def say_hi
      puts "hi123"
    end
  end
end
```

When I setup **whenever**, it adds this to cron:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/user123/my_app && bundle exec script/runner -e production '\''Module1.say_hi'\'''
```

It doesn't work. This command when I'm running it directly in the terminal returns:

```
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
```

Then I try this:

```
cd /home/user123/my_app && bundle exec script/runner -e production 'Module1.say_hi'
```

And now an error is:

```
bundler: command not found: script/runner
```

However, my rails application is working well; bundle and other stuff are installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bundle exec not working with crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19831878/bundle-exec-not-working-with-crontab)

Answer (score 1):

> You can also ensure your PATH ends up in the crontab, by putting the following at the top of the schedule.rb file:

```
env :PATH, ENV['PATH']
```

> [chek this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/whenever-gem/yRLt3f2jrfU/Exu3xfCo8DAJ)
>   If above solution don't work for you, try:

```
env :GEM_PATH, ENV['GEM_PATH']
```